# React Router onEnter Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i'm trying to add route authentication to my reactjs app on react router, but whenever I add the authentication function i created to the on enter property on the specific route i get the following error.

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

**My Routes**

```
// libraries
import React from '../node_modules/react';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute, Redirect} from '../node_modules/react-router';
// route middleware
import requiresAuth from '../middleware/requiresAuth';
// components
import App from '../modules/other/app.jsx'; 
import Dashboard from '../modules/stats/dashboard.jsx'; 
import Login from '../modules/auth/login.jsx';
import NotFound from '../modules/errors/notfound.jsx';
// routes
export const routes =
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} onEnter={requiresAuth} />
            <Route path="dashboard" name="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requiresAuth} />
            <Route path="login" name="login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="*" name="notfound" component={NotFound} />
        </Route>
    </Router>;
```

**My authentication function**

```
const requiresAuth = (nextState, replace) => {
    if (!loggedIn()) {
        replace({
            path: '/login',
            state: {next: nextState.location.pathname}
        });
    }
}

const loggedIn = () => {
    return !!localStorage.token;
}

export default requiresAuth;
```

Comment: Can you upload your entire app/routes files code?

Comment: @RandomUser i just did

Comment: First thing first, when you import a module which you have installed using `npm`, you can use its name directly instead of providing relative path to it while importing it, so change `import React from '../node_modules/react';` to `import React from 'react';` and do the same for `react-router`

Comment: Try changing your `replace` method with this code `replace({
    pathname: '/login',
    state: {nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error, You have to change your `replace` code from

```
replace({
    path: '/login',
    state: {next: nextState.location.pathname}
});
```

To

```
replace({
  pathname: '/login',
  state: {nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and make a change to how localStorage.token is returned.

```
const loggedIn = () => {
    return localStorage.token;
}
```